# Finding diagonal heat source instead of vertical and horizontal

Tags: python, arrays, image, image-processing

I am having trouble with finding diagonal heat source instead of vertical and horizontal shown in the image. If I am to show a diagonal line or a curve how can I input a function? The output is a gif file and I was wondering if I can somehow recode the iteration so that it stops when there is maximum heat everywhere.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation



print("2D heat equation solver")

plate_length = 50
max_iter_time = 200

alpha = 2
delta_x = 1

delta_t = (delta_x ** 2)/(4 * alpha)
gamma = (alpha * delta_t) / (delta_x ** 2)

# Initialize solution: the grid of u(k, i, j)
u = np.empty((max_iter_time, plate_length, plate_length))

# Initial condition everywhere inside the grid
u_initial = 0

# Boundary conditions
u_top = 100.0
u_left = 100.0
u_bottom = 0.0
u_right = 100.0

# Set the initial condition
u.fill(u_initial)

# Set the boundary conditions
u[:, 40, 20:30] = u_top
u[:, 20:25, 15:20] = u_left
u[:, :1, 1:] = u_bottom
u[:, 20:30, 40] = u_right


def calculate(u):
    for k in range(0, max_iter_time-1, 1):
        for i in range(1, plate_length-1, delta_x):
            for j in range(1, plate_length-1, delta_x):
                if (20 <= j <= 29 and i == 40) or (20 <= i <= 29 and j == 40) or (20<=i<=24 and 15<=j<=19):
                    continue
                u[k + 1, i, j] = gamma * (u[k][i+1][j] + u[k][i-1][j] + u[k][i][j+1] + u[k][i][j-1] - 4*u[k][i][j]) + u[k][i][j]
        
    return u


def plotheatmap(u_k, k):
    # Clear the current plot figure
    plt.clf()

    plt.title(f"Temperature at t = {k*delta_t:.3f} unit time")
    plt.xlabel("x")
    plt.ylabel("y")

    # This is to plot u_k (u at time-step k)
    plt.pcolormesh(u_k, cmap=plt.cm.jet, vmin=0, vmax=100)
    plt.colorbar()

    return plt

# Do the calculation here
u = calculate(u)

def animate(k):
    plotheatmap(u[k], k)


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(plt.figure(), animate, interval=1, frames=max_iter_time, repeat=False)
anim
anim.save("heat_equation_solution.gif")
```

I am trying to find a diagonal line instead of an array. Here is an image of what I managed to do but I need a diagonal line.
[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. Are you looking for lines or arrays of something? Why are you looking for diagonal lines in an image that doesn't appear to have any? Please click [edit] and try to clarify. Thank you.

Comment: I agree with Mark, this needs a lot of clarification. Because of the [image-processing] tag, I assume your input is an image? But your code does’t seem to deal with images at all, it looks like you have a simulation. Please explain in steps, what is your input, what algorithm you apply to accomplish your goal, and most importantly what your goal is.

Comment: First please provide a code that also gives us your output

Comment: Thank you for the replies. This is my first question and I apologize for not making it clearer. I have edited the description with full code of output. It would mean a world to me if someone helps me with the later part regarding iteration also. Thank you.